# Calculating APR from a Token/USDC Farming Pool

Tags: solidity, web3js, defi, staking

I was trying to look at how to calculate the APR of a PRNTR USDC Farming Pool and i struggled a lot as I can't really find a example nor a formula close to it. I studied the contract but still can't find a clue from it. Can anyone please help...

Here is the contract:
[Link to contact](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xfda1cf6261dcabaa29b3e464f78717ffb54b8a63)

Comment: Your link isn't working for me, mind updating it?

Comment: Updated! Thanks for notice it out

Comment: Have you found any example,can you give me one

Comment: You may need a fixed-point math library to calculate APRs. I recommend using [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math/tree/main/test) (disclaimer: I'm the author).